# Passing objects as props while retaining keys, using object map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object array, **obj**, like so:

```
{
    "root": [
        {
            "key": "mihome",
            "label": "home",
            "action": "url",
            "submenu": "none"
        },
        {
            "key": "signin",
            "label": "sign in",
            "action": "url",
            "submenu": "none"
        }
    ],
    "mainMenu": [
        {
            "key": "unito",
            "label": "unit o",
            "action": "url",
            "submenu": "none"
        },
        {
            "key": "unitt",
            "label": "unit t",
            "action": "url",
            "submenu": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which I want to iterate out as components in React JS, using object map, like so:

```
return (
    <div className='menud'>
        {obj["root"] !== undefined ?
            Object.entries(obj).map(([key, menuItems]) => 
            <MenuList menuArray={obj[key]} key={key} menuKey={key} pcbClick={handleItemClick} />)
            : null
        }
    </div>
);
```

This works mostly as I intend, except I'm struggling to figure out how to retain the key name of each object, as they're mapped, which would require passing an object array rather than on array of objects. e.g. right now the first  would receive a menuArray prop of:

```
[
        {
            "key": "mihome",
            "label": "home",
            "action": "url",
            "submenu": "none"
        },
        {
            "key": "signin",
            "label": "sign in",
            "action": "url",
            "submenu": "none"
        }
    ],
```

whereas I would like it to receive

```
{
root: [
        {
            "key": "mihome",
            "label": "home",
            "action": "url",
            "submenu": "none"
        },
        {
            "key": "signin",
            "label": "sign in",
            "action": "url",
            "submenu": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

etc. as it iterates. I was looking into using JSON.stringify and just assigning key names and '{' characters but this feels like it's adding needless conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
return (
    <div className='menud'>
        {obj["root"] !== undefined ?
            Object.entries(obj).map(([key, menuItems]) => 
            <MenuList menuArray={{[key]: menuItems}} key={key} menuKey={key} pcbClick={handleItemClick} />)
            : null
        }
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Since `key` is a computed property I suggest we use bracket notation:
`{ [key]: menuItems }`

Comment: @anonDelta, yes of course

Comment: I think my Googling powers are failing me I tried to word this every way I could, thinking there was a simple syntax I was missing. And there it is! Many thanks. Although I missed such a simple change, I'm glad it's straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Another answer was already given but I would like to propose a simpler solution.
You can just spread your object keys on the component, given the object keys and component props are named equally: https://kevinyckim33.medium.com/jsx-spread-operator-component-props-meaning-3c9bcadd2493

Comment: I hadn't thought of this method, nice suggestion. Right now I'm going with the planned approach but I'm going to look back at this to see if it makes my sub components benefit on the roadmap.